# Typo3-9.x Felogin- login problem with multiple domains

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, felogin

I have two domains. E.g-:: a.domain.com, b.domain.com . In both domains I have used the fe_login plugin. In backend I have 2 folder Fe-User1 for a.domain.com and other Fe-User2 for b.domain. And both folder have different login users.

So the problem is that a.domain.com users can login in b.domain.com login panel and viceversa. I want different users for both domains. In database table both domain users details are added but with different pid.

So I can differentiate users for a.domain.com and b.domain.com?

Could anyone please tell me how can I do this? How can I write typoscript for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set the constant `styles.content.loginform.pid` on each domain to it special folder?

Comment: Thank you for the reponse :) . Yes I have this line of code. for both different domains I have defined different storage pid. E.g -  styles.content.loginform.pid = 1 for a.domain.com and styles.content.loginform.pid = 2 for b.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

In Flexform "User Storage Page", respectively in TypoScript "plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.storagePid" is the way to define certain sysfolders for allowed fe_users. This way, for both Login plugins you can define separate sysfolders as used storage.

Comment: Thank you for the response :). I have defined different storagePid for both domains. Fe-users1 sys_folder has different users. and Fe_user2 sys_folder has different users. But Fe_users2 are able to login in a.domain.com and Fe_user1 are able to login in b.domain.com. Right now it is working like this

Comment: Can't reproduce that. 

In case of defining the storagePids via Typoscript: have you verified that they are taken into account (-> TypoScript Object Browser)?

Do you use any other extension that might crash the core behavior?

Comment: HI @Julian My Problem has been solved. In Fe-User folder there are 'website user group' so I have created Group 1 and edit that Group 1 then there is one option 'Lock to domain' so I have mention my domain name there. so same thing I have done for second domain. Created another group and assigned another domain name to 'Lock to domain' option. This work for me. :). Now both domains have different user to access websites

Answer (score 0):

The authentication part of the core is executed before any TS configuration is loaded. It does not know about a sys-folder restriction from there.

See `\TYPO3\CMS\Sv\AuthenticationService::getUser()`

The allowed storage must be present as POST parameter named `pid`.
(felogin usually generated the login form accordingly.)

The initialization happens in: `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController::initFEuser`

Comment: My Problem has been solved. In Fe-User folder there are 'website user group' so I have created Group 1 and edit that Group 1 then there is one option 'Lock to domain' so I have mention my domain name there. so same thing I have done for second domain. Created another group and assigned another domain name to 'Lock to domain' option. This work for me. :). Now both domains have different user to access websites